# Need to extract value from html response using regex in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am trying to extract a value from HTML response but unable to. Can anyone please help me with regular expression for the below response. I tried below regular expression but, it is capturing whole response starting from Select to '"'.

I need to extract value **2** from the highlighted line in response.

```
Select Region<\/option>.*<option selected="selected" value="(.+?)"
```

Input:

```
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 form-group ">
            <label>      Region</label>
            <select class="Grid="0" id="RegionId" name="RegionId"><option value="">Select Region</option>
                <option value="9">IDX-ACO REGION CA</option>
                <option value="1">IDX-REGION I</option>
                **<option selected="selected" value="2">IDX-REGION II</option>**
                <option value="3">IDX-REGION III</option>
                <option value="5">IDX-REGION IV</option>
            </select>      
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748).

JMeter comes with [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) which provides option to extract various attributes values via [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp).

In your case it would be something like:

```
option[selected=selected]
```

if you want to include the parent [`<select>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp):

```
select[id=RegionId] option[selected=selected]
```

in both cases the attribute will be `value`

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. Yes, I have to add select tag as well and your solution works fine.

Comment: So, if I have multiple select tags like select[id=RegionId], select[id=SiteId], select[id=ProductId] in the response but option tag is same everywhere like option[selected=selected], should I add multiple CSS Selector Extractor or we can extract all the values in one go?

Answer (score 1):

This RegEx will do the job

```
/<option selected="selected" value="\d+">(.*?)<\/option>/mg
```